# Force c++ compiler to warn about all stack instances of an object

Tags: c++, optimization, stack, compiler-warnings, simd

I'd like to refactor a large codebase for optimization purposes, where moving forward, I'd like to prevent stack usage of a class type. For instance:

```
class noStack
{
    int x;
    // I don't want this on the stack
};

void foo()
{
    noStack bar; // I want the compiler to issue a warning here.

    class moreNoStack { int a; noStack b; }

    moreNoStack baz; // Also warn here because baz is on the stack and contains a noStack
}
```

But on the other hand, I want the compiler to ignore this:

```
noStack g_globalNoStack; // no warning

class foo
{
    noStack bar; // no warning
};

foo g_globalFoo; // no warning

void func()
{
    foo* p = (foo*)malloc(sizeof(foo)); // no warning
    foo* q = new foo; // no warning
}
```

On the other hand, if there's no way to get the compiler to do this, then can I go the other way around? Meaning don't warn about stack usage but always warn about global instances or contained members of a class? I can accomplish this problem either way.

Comment: I don't think such a compiler option exists for any known compiler. Independent of that, it sounds like a very bad idea, which only helps introducing bugs but not helping with performance.

Comment: And do you understand that your `malloc` line does *not* the same thing as the `new` line below?

Comment: I suggest you research *static analyzers* for C++.

Comment: @deviantfan, yes, but I don't care in this case.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, Thanks, I'm googling it. Do you have any in mind that might be good candidates?

Comment: Here are some that I have used:  Parasoft, Coverity, Klocwork, PC-Lint.

Comment: I notice that you tagged this with `simd`. Are you *actually* trying to ensure proper *alignment* of your class? If so, there are better ways to do this, using compiler-specific alignment attributes.

Comment: @ZanLynx, that's a theme of the problem, but not really my goal. There's a 4 float vector class that doesn't use SSE. I tried to convert it to use SSE, but that forced 16 byte alignment of the class. We have multiple allocators that would need to guarantee 16 byte alignment, and class sizes would change unexpectedly. I wanted to compromise by allowing the existing vec4 class only exist in storage outside of function scope, and convert existing function scoped vec4's to a new SIMD type, but store the results to the old unaligned type.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this by making the class constructors private and then creating either a class static or free friend factory function to construct instances for you.

The factory function would always allocate on the heap and return a pointer (preferably a smart pointer).

Then you would get error messages everywhere the code attempts to construct a class instance and you can go fix them to use the factory function instead. And since there is no other way to construct the object you can be sure all instances are allocated on the heap.

You could also create a specialized memory pool for these objects. If they are uncommonly large or otherwise strange, that might help reduce fragmentation.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I'm after at all. I want to permit construction anywhere the object exists as a contained member variable or global, but not scoped within a function.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to force the compiler to generate a warning other than implement it in the compiler. What I would use is clang-tidy and integrate it with CI system. Here is a simple tutorial for clang-tidy:
http://bbannier.github.io/blog/2015/05/02/Writing-a-basic-clang-static-analysis-check.html

Comment: Thanks. This on the surface seems to be viable down the road if we ever port to clang. For now, though, I don't think it's going to happen.